# Copy specific column data USING BUTTON from Book1 to Book2 based on column header matching

Tags: excel, macros, vba

In Excel, I would like to copy SPECIFIC columns data from Book1 to Book2 based on column header matching. Book1 and Book2 has same heading. I need single button in sheet2 of Book1 to execute this copy macro or VBscript.

Also, in Book2, I have some columns with data in row1. This data should be populated automatically (SAME DATA) in all rows down based on the number of rows data copied from Book1.

Comment: please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to receive the most effective help from this site.

Answer (score 0):

I tried below code as found in this site. It works fine. Now I need the second part of my question.

```
Sub CopyHeaders()
Dim header As Range, headers As Range
Set headers = Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1:Z1")

For Each header In headers
    If GetHeaderColumn(header.Value) > 0 Then
        Range(header.Offset(1, 0), header.End(xlDown)).Copy Destination:=Workbooks("Book2.xlsm").Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(2, GetHeaderColumn(header.Value))
    End If
Next
End Sub

Function GetHeaderColumn(header As String) As Integer
   Dim headers As Range
   Set headers = Workbooks("Book2.xlsm").Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1:Z1")
   GetHeaderColumn = IIf(IsNumeric(Application.Match(header, headers, 0)), Application.Match(header, headers, 0), 0)
End Function
```